# How many layers in your PCB? 2, 4, 6, 8

Tags: pcb-design

Production of multi-layer prototype PCBs is becoming increasingly cheap, what with places like JLCPCB, PCBWay, Digikey, Mouser, etcetera, offering multi-layer production services.  Multi-layer boards offer advantages such as full-coverage ground-plane and power-plane layers.

With respect to projects that include both 5V and 3.3V parts (and, potentially, other voltages,) would there be any advantage to including separate power-plane/ground-plane layers for each voltage?

A 6 layer board with two voltages could be:

- Top layer - traces
- 2nd-layer - ground plane
- 3rd layer - 5V
- 4th layer - ground plane
- 5th layer 3.3V
- 6th layer ground plane

A four layer board could be four layers without the additional ground planes:

- traces
- 5V
- 3.3V
- GND

Is that uselessly complicated excess for typical PCBs?

Comment: Since 5V is not that widely used on high density logic boards, my guess is that you don't need 6 layers to route it and can instead put both 3.3V and 5V on the same layer.  But it depends on your board and what you're trying to route.

Comment: It mostly depends on how tight the layout is. It is true that there's never a reason to have less than 4 layers, but to go beyond that typically means you have size constraints, for example caused by dedicated RF areas where nothing else is allowed to be routed.

Comment: I guess it depends on your market and cost target.  But I haven't seen a board done at my place with less than 14 layers for many, many years now.

Comment: Having a separate ground plane for each voltage doesn't gain you anything, it may even introduce problems as the circuits all share a common ground even if their supplies are different.

Comment: I recommend this video, which looks into your question in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdCJxdR7L_I

Comment: @Finbarr Oh, is that the reasoning behind all those strange ground planes? I was wondering why OP decided to do that.

Answer (score 11):

You have too few trace layers. This will be a needlessly challenging to route given it's a 6 layer board. The 6th layer in particular is a waste given the 5th layer is already adjacent to another ground layer.

You largely turned a 6 layer PCB into a single layer PCB as far as routing effort is concerned. Not even a two-layer PCB but single layer. Signal layers can use power planes as a reference plane. Or, just put both power planes at the center. Then all trace and signal layers have an adjacent ground plane even when you turn the 6th layer into a signal layer.

So a much better 6-layer stackup would be:

1. signal
2. ground
3. 3.3V
4. 5V
5. ground
6. signal

Your proposed four layer stackup is pretty bad. The ground plane is so far away from the trace plane and only adjacent to one other plane. A much better version of that is:

1. signal
2. ground
3. 3.3V
4. 5V

But that turns a 4 layer board into a single layer board for routing purposes. What you really want is:

1. signal
2. ground
3. 3.3V/5V
4. signal

Look up Henry Ott's book Electromagnetic Compatibility or the resources on mirrors of his website. It has all you need to know about layers and routing. He died a few years ago so his original website was taken down but I believe mirrors still exist. The book is really really good. A great loss. You can also search my answers on here which almost always draw from the book with screen shots when talking about PCB layers and routing.

Comment: What benefits does 1. signal 2. ground 3. 3.3V 4. 5V 5. ground 6. signal have over 1. signal 2. ground 3. 3.3V 4. signal 5. 5V 6. signal? Assuming you got properly stable voltage planes and aren't working with high-frequency components, how much benefit is that 2nd ground plane really?

Comment: @Mast Well the second one gives you a 3rd trace layer, but the price you pay is that the reference plane for two signal layers are power layers which means that to provide a path for the return current, you have to use something other than a via to the ground layer (i.e. a nearby decoupling cap to where the signal changes layers). That means higher impedance and more noise.

Comment: @Mast Check out the video in the question comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdCJxdR7L_I

Comment: @Mast With the 6-layer stackup I suggested, the two signal layers also have different reference planes but since they are both the same potential you can just connect both gnd layers together with vias nearby where signals change layers

Answer (score 6):

My experience is mainly with fairly small (maybe 1 x 3 cm) boards requiring high speed signals (up to 25 Gb/s digital)

For a 6 layer board with two voltages I might use

- Top layer - traces and components
- 2nd-layer - ground plane
- 3rd layer - 5V / 3.3V split plane
- 4th layer - low-speed traces
- 5th layer - ground plane
- 6th layer -  traces and components

This gives you three routing layers rather than one, which lets you create some space around your high-speed traces to avoid unwanted coupling to or from them.

It does require you to group your 5 V components and 3.3 V components sensibly so that a split power plane can serve all the loads with low impedance paths.

It's also very common to have to use 8 layers and buried vias to adequately route everything in the kind of projects I've done.

If you don't need controlled impedance you can probably get away with one ground layer, one (split) power plane, and 4 signal layers.

Answer (score 5):

A whole plane devoted to power is a very expensive luxury. Use traces.

A whole plane devoted to ground, and not turned into a lace curtain by stealing some of it for 'only a few' last minute tracks, is a very worthwhile investment.

Once you get to needing multiple layers, a pair of layers, either side of a PCB core, make an extremely useful 'Manhattan' routing (NS on one side, EW on the other) pair, permitting buried vias, to save top and bottom real estate for components.

Comment: I like your Manhattan routing analogy, is it a ter you ound somewhere or came up yourself? Because using the NS, EW routing I knew about, but never with that term.

Comment: @JonathanG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_geometry

Comment: @JonathanG It's a term that was used at work from when I joined, so I assumed it was in widespread usage for the whole of my career. I now find that people are still discovering it. it's a convenient term.

Comment: @Hearth thanks for the link, although I know how Manhattan and more cities are laid out in USA. Still nice to read up on it.

Comment: @JonathanG I meant more to show that "manhattan" is a common descriptor for this sort of thing in mathematics.

Comment: Stay away from blind and buried vias. These are high density integrations and will easily double or triple the cost of a board, even in prototype. You also want to avoid via in pad, and microvias for the same reasons.

Answer (score 4):

One of the benefits of multiple layers is that you can build layer pairs (e.g. GND|3.3v) which act as very good high-frequency capable capacitors if spaced very tight together.

Yes, multiple layers are a good thing, but most circuits have relaxed requirements that do not need additional layers. You can do good layouts (in terms of EMC) with only two layers.

Think of a ham and cheese sandwich: Multilayer ham/cheese does not make the sandwich **much** better for most people. But multilayer ham/cheese could make the difference for the sandwich expert.

Comment: What about the cheese?

Comment: Ok, I added cheese to the sandwich.